# Does Ubuntu generally support HDMI out?

Tags: 11.04, hdmi

I'm planning to buy a new LCD tv with Full HD and with HDMI inputs. My laptop (acer 5740) has HDMI output, but will Ubuntu support it?

Comment: From my experience yes - I have a Dell Inspiron 15R and a Toshiba NB550D that both have HDMI output I use regularly to watch media on my LCD TV. I do need to change the sound output preferences in order to get the sound to work each time however. Both laptops have ATI graphics cards FWIW.

Comment: to get sound through HDMI you may need to open Sound Settings and set the device to Digital HDMI in both the Hardware and Output tabs. If left at Analogue you may get a visual signal but not audio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The HDMI factor is not Ubuntu relevant, what you need to check is if your video card works with Ubuntu since the HDMI output will be configured using the drivers for your card.

Has a short answer: Ubuntu will support anything that your drivers will.

Your laptop has a Intel GMA HD integrated card that is supported out of the box by Ubuntu. I am assuming all the work it will be is to plugin your screen and configure the drivers so its recognized as a 2nd screen. It wont be very hard to do, maybe not as easy as in Windows ofc but, still doable and simple.

Comment: I wish I could up vote more this answer. I have pointed several people here, specially the part about "Ubuntu will support anything that your drivers will"